# Jump straight to the asset trading page on Ardor Ignis via a shared url link?

Tags: ardor, ignis, child-chain

Is there a way to jump directly to the asset trading page in Ardor without logging in? Just by using a shared url link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it like this:

https://testardor.enchantaddress.com/index.html?account=ARDOR-XK4R-7VJU-6EQG-7R335&chain=IGNIS&page=asset_exchange&asset=16056551815000754623

Using the url parameters you can go directly to the page and asset.

Alot of the functionality is handled in the nrs.js file. Just search for "getUrlPara" and you'll see the various ways to get to a page via just a url without logging in.